# ноут с убунту не видит внешний инт

Tags: администрирование

винт, новенький, только принесла с магазина: Samsung 860 Evo-Series 500GB 2.5" SATA III V-NAND 3bitMLC
карман: Maiwo для HDD 2.5" USB 3.0 K2568 Black
Винт стоит в кармане, мигает, внешне все ок.
Но в системе винт не видно (с флешками такой проблемы нет).

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Диск /dev/loop0: 199,46 MiB, 209141760 байт, 408480 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop1: 199,44 MiB, 209117184 байт, 408432 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop2: 282,38 MiB, 296083456 байт, 578288 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop3: 281,62 MiB, 295280640 байт, 576720 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop4: 61,65 MiB, 64626688 байт, 126224 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop5: 162,99 MiB, 170881024 байт, 333752 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop6: 55,48 MiB, 58159104 байт, 113592 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop7: 423,15 MiB, 443703296 байт, 866608 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/sda: 238,49 GiB, 256060514304 байт, 500118192 секторов
Disk model: SAMSUNG SSD PM87
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт
Тип метки диска: dos
Идентификатор диска: 0xd032c9f9

Устр-во    Загрузочный  начало     Конец   Секторы Размер Идентификатор Тип
/dev/sda1  *              2048   1050623   1048576   512M             b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2              1052670 500117503 499064834   238G             5 Расширенный
/dev/sda5              1052672 500117503 499064832   238G            83 Linux


Диск /dev/loop8: 55,46 MiB, 58142720 байт, 113560 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop9: 328 KiB, 335872 байт, 656 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop10: 99,22 MiB, 104030208 байт, 203184 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop11: 140 KiB, 143360 байт, 280 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop12: 62,9 MiB, 65105920 байт, 127160 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop13: 93,53 MiB, 98062336 байт, 191528 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop14: 218,102 MiB, 229629952 байт, 448496 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop15: 470,51 MiB, 493355008 байт, 963584 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop16: 288 KiB, 294912 байт, 576 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop17: 397,44 MiB, 416735232 байт, 813936 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop18: 61,74 MiB, 64720896 байт, 126408 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop19: 303,33 MiB, 318054400 байт, 621200 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop20: 1,1 GiB, 1082556416 байт, 2114368 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop21: 51,2 MiB, 53501952 байт, 104496 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop22: 64,79 MiB, 67915776 байт, 132648 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop23: 99,15 MiB, 103964672 байт, 203056 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop24: 217,92 MiB, 228478976 байт, 446248 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop25: 51,4 MiB, 53522432 байт, 104536 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop26: 462,59 MiB, 485044224 байт, 947352 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop27: 32,28 MiB, 33841152 байт, 66096 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop28: 503,62 MiB, 528064512 байт, 1031376 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop29: 175,38 MiB, 183885824 байт, 359152 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop30: 272,12 MiB, 285339648 байт, 557304 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop31: 237,27 MiB, 248786944 байт, 485912 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop32: 2,68 MiB, 2789376 байт, 5448 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop33: 533,7 MiB, 559607808 байт, 1092984 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop34: 197,48 MiB, 207060992 байт, 404416 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop35: 1,1 GiB, 1082560512 байт, 2114376 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop36: 32,28 MiB, 33841152 байт, 66096 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop37: 272,23 MiB, 285446144 байт, 557512 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop38: 175,37 MiB, 183881728 байт, 359144 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop39: 86,71 MiB, 90906624 байт, 177552 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop40: 44 KiB, 45056 байт, 88 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/loop41: 111,54 MiB, 116944896 байт, 228408 секторов
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 512 байт / 512 байт


Диск /dev/sdb: 465,78 GiB, 500107862016 байт, 976773168 секторов
Disk model: SSD 860 EVO 500G
Единицы: секторов по 1 * 512 = 512 байт
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 4096 байт
Размер I/O (минимальный/оптимальный): 4096 байт / 4096 байт
```

Comment: Ну у вас же написано, `/dev/sdb` это как раз ваш SSD 860 Evo на 500 Гб. Значит видит.

Comment: Создайте на нем таблицу разделов и файловую систему. Можно использовать GParted или cfdisk.